# ActiveRecord has_one through association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a SitePlan and a PriceSchedule that should be associated through a join table, Pricing. Here's my models:

```
class Pricing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site_plan
  belongs_to :price_schedule
end

class SitePlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price_schedule, through: :pricings
end

class PriceSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :site_plans, through: :pricings
end
```

don't understand why I get an error when I do... `SitePlan.new.price_schedule`

error:
`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :pricings in model SitePlan`

schema:

```
create_table "price_schedules", force: true do |t|
  t.boolean  "seasonal"
  t.string   "weekly_discount"
  t.string   "monthly_discount"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "pricings", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "site_plan_id"
  t.integer  "price_schedule_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "site_plans", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple question really, but I'll leave what I found for future googlers.

I forgot to specify the `has_one :pricing` relationship in SitePlan and the `has_many :pricings` relationship in PriceSchedule. Apparently, there's less magic going on here than I thought, `through` couldnt find a reference to `:pricing` or `:pricings` because I hadn't declared them.